# Pi Hole -- Safari (mac) fails to load site, Chrome doesn't

Tags: safari, google-chrome, dns

I have recently run into issues accessing a specific site (https://www.inoreader.com/all_articles) in Safari 15.5 on macOS Monterey.  The site loads *something*, as I can see some results in the `Network->Response` preview in Developer Tools.  However, nothing is fully rendered on-screen.  The site loads perfectly via Chrome.  This is a new issue in Safari, as I was able to hit that site for years with no issue.

Further compounding the problem is that I am using PiHole as an ad blocker.  This setup has been in place for years, as well, and never gave me an issue.  When I remove PiHole from the mix entirely -- no ad blocking, use router DHCP instead, etc. -- Safari is once again able to render the site with no problem.

I've tried flushing my DNS cache and restarting the DNS responder by running

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

I've tried keeping the PiHole config in place for DHCP but disabling all ad blocking.  None of those things worked.  Any idea what else I could try?

Comment: Works fine on my mac with the same version of macOS and Safari, have you cleared history in Safari. Also deleted any site-specific cookies?

Comment: Yes, I've done all of the above.  Cleared cache.  Cleared history.  Cleared cookies.